# Textblock FormatString DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf

I would add to my example some text (Temp is: X Celcius degree), now my TextBlock return only digits. Help please

```
<TextBlock 
    x:Name="aktualtemp" 
    Text="{Binding , StringFormat='Temp is: \{0\} Celcius degree'}"/>
```

and this is my line from function ("parsing xml").

```
aktualtemp.DataContext = document.Element("data").Element("weather").Element("hourly").Element("tempC").Value;
```

What I should write here after Binding? What source, function, element? `Text="{Binding ? ,...}`

Comment: Looking at your `DataContext`, I'm concerned you are doing more work than you have to.  By using the `DataContext` property the way you are, you cannot take full advantage of data-binding in the first place.  Once your data changes, you will need to reapply the `DataContext`.  WPF allows you to propagate changed to your UI automatically.

Comment: A side note: please don't post the same question multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you look at the [Data Binding Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  It should help you understand `DataContexts` a bit better.

Basically a `DataContext` is an object which typically has CLR properties, it contains the data model you want.  In WPF, the `DataContext` is inherited by parent elements.

Typically, I set the `DataContext` of the `MainWindow`, and let all of the `UIElements` in my window inherit it.  Then, for your binding you must specify the `Path` to the CLR property you want to bind to.  In your case, you are trying to specify the `Path` by using the binding clauses' default property.
In other words, the binding clause expects that the first property is your CLR property name.  If you want to specify the property name later, you must use `Path=CLR_property_name_here` in your binding clause.

Answer (score 0):

Just `Binding` the `Text` to its `DataContext`, as for the format, just write it the way you want:

Please note: Don't use *`* or *\*, just write in plain text.

```
<TextBlock 
        x:Name="aktualtemp" 
        Text="{Binding, StringFormat=Temp is: {0} Celcius degree}"/>
```

Comment: I had to remove the comma, and everything works as it should. Thank you :)